# Weird SQL UPDATE query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a query that I'm not sure how to write. I have two tables that have the same structure:

```
Table1 (id, value1, value2, value_of_interest)

Table2 (id, value1, value2, value_of_interest)
```

I want to find all rows on `Table2` where both `value1` and `value2` match, and where `Table1.value_of_interest` is empty, and copy those values from `Table2`. So the SQL for that would be:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.value_of_interest = Table2.value_of_interest
FROM Table2
WHERE Table1.value_of_interest == ''
AND Table1.value1 == Table2.value1
AND Table1.value2 == Table2.value2
```

However, there is also the possibility that the set of matching rows on `Table2` do not have a unique `value_of_interest`. I only want to update `Table1.value_of_interest` if the set of matching rows from `Table2` have a unique `value_of_interest`.

For example, say we have

```
Table1(0, 1, 1, '')
Table2(0, 1, 1, 1)
Table2(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Then I would update `Table1.value_of_interest` with 1. But if I had:

```
Table1(0, 1, 1, '')
Table2(0, 1, 1, 1)
Table2(0, 1, 1, 2)
```

Then I would do nothing. I was thinking something along the lines of `GROUP BY` with an aggregate function and testing for `DISTINCT` values equaling 1 but I can't figure it out. Any advice would be appreciated.

PS. I'm using PostgreSQL and SQLAlchemy but I couldn't do this using the ORM so I'm trying to do a straight SQL query.

Comment: What about the id's matching?  Does that not matter?

Comment: No, ids don't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simples way would be to add a [`NOT EXISTS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-anti-join:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET    value_of_interest = t2a.value_of_interest
FROM  (
   SELECT DISTINCT value1, value2, value_of_interest
   FROM   table2
   ) t2a
WHERE  t1.value_of_interest = ''
AND    t2a.value_of_interest IS DISTINCT FROM ''
AND    t1.value1 = t2a.value1
AND    t1.value2 = t2a.value2
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   table2 t2b
   WHERE  t2b.value1 = t2.value1
   AND    t2b.value2 = t2.value2
   AND    t2b.value_of_interest <> t2a.value_of_interest
   );
```

Also:

- No table qualification for target columns in the `SET` clause.

```
SET Table1.value_of_interest = ...
```

I quote [the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html):

> Do not include the table's name in the specification of a target column — for example, `UPDATE tab SET tab.col = 1` is invalid.
>
> No `==` in SQL, just `=`.
>
> `t2.value_of_interest IS DISTINCT FROM ''` .. to avoid empty UPDATEs (changing nothing for full cost).
>
> To avoid multiple redundant updates from duplicates, I converted the plain table `t2a` to a subquery folding those.

Comment: Can you please explain your first note: "No table qualification for target columns in the SET clause."? Do you mean you deliberately left off t1 on the value_of_interest in the SET clause?d Why?

Comment: @ericso: Because it's illegal syntax that wouldn't work. I added a bit to make it clear.

Comment: also there is a ";" after your last AND clause and before the AND NOT EXITS. That's a typo right?

Comment: @ericso: Right. Artefact from switching lines.

Comment: I'm trying this and I'm getting an error: ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) column "value1" does not exist
LINE 1: ...rest = t2a.value_of_interest FROM (SELECT DISTINCT value1, ...  Any ideas from this? I can elaborate or maybe I should start a new question.

Comment: Note, in order to get this to work with Python/Pyramid/SQLAlchemy, I had to wrap the entire query string in ''' <query> ''' and double-quote each column name (e.g. "value1", t1."value_of_interest") since PostgreSQL will convert the column names to lower case.

Comment: @ericso: All [identifiers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) in my query are lower case for this reason.